# Templates in Angular testing with Karma, Unexpected request

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, gulp, karma-jasmine

I want to test my directive, which has a template. I'm using Karma with Jasmine framework, gulp compile all html files to www/templates. When i'm running test i've got this error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET ../templates/directives/my_directive.html
```

What is wrong with this files?

This is my spec:

```
describe 'Directive: my-directive', ->
  beforeEach module 'myApp'
  beforeEach module 'myApp-templates'

  compile = {}
  rootScope = {}
  element = {}
  scope = {}

  beforeEach ->
    inject (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) ->

      compile = _$compile_
      rootScope = _$rootScope_
      scope = rootScope
      element = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>')
      compile(element)(scope)
      angular.element(document.body).append(element)
      scope.$apply()

  describe 'content', ->
    it 'should contain', ->
      console.log element
```

Directive:

```
angular.module 'myApp.directives'

.directive 'myDirective', ->
  restrict: 'AE'
  replace: true
  templateUrl: '../templates/directives/my_directive.html'
```

And karma.conf.coffee:

```
files: [
  ...
  'www/templates/**/*.html'
  ...
]

preprocessors:
  'www/templates/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor:
  moduleName: 'myApp-templates'
  stripPrefix: 'www/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete '../' in templateURL of directive...